# How can I make a link automatically open in the Oculus Quest browser?

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

I'm working on importing 3D models into the Oculus Quest, and for now, I'm just trying out the workflow of:

Scanning a 3D object --> exporting into OBJ file --> exporting to Sketchfab --> opening Sketchfab link in Quest

I know there are a few ways to open links in Quest (sending yourself a message, saw one person who used Google Tasks), but I'm trying to get this process as automated as possible. Does anyone know how I can automatically share a link from my iPhone and have it open directly on Oculus Quest's browser?